# Wordcloud: Bigger font for lower tf-idf values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tf-idf, word-cloud

I am trying to form a word cloud for the tf-idf values:

Below are the tf-idf values in the dataframe. When I try to form a word cloud, the values with higher values, in this case "seat - 2.57" is shown in largest font. But I need the vice-versa. "Nice - 2.088" to have a bigger font as it is of higher importance.

```
[[u'nice' 2.0886619578149417]
 [u'owl' 2.2729656758128876]
 [u'person' 2.386294361119891]
 [u'read' 2.455287232606842]
 [u'seat' 2.5766480896111092]]
```

Below is the code:

```
print(top_10.values)
d = {}
for a, x in top_10.values:
    d[a] = x

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

wordcloud = WordCloud()
wordcloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies=d)
plt.figure( figsize=(20,10) )
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use different frequencies to supply to the wordcloud.

E.g.

```
d[a] = 3-x
```

or

```
d[a] = 1./x
```

Complete example:

```
top_10 = lambda :""
top_10.values = [[u'nice', 2.0886619578149417],
                 [u'owl', 2.2729656758128876],
                 [u'person', 2.386294361119891],
                 [u'read', 2.455287232606842],
                 [u'seat', 2.5766480896111092]]
d = {}
for a, x in top_10.values:
    d[a] = 3-x

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

wordcloud = WordCloud()
wordcloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies=d)
plt.figure( figsize=(5,3) )
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]